# Why am I getting "unsupported :except_all in keyword query expression" in my Elixir Ecto query?

Tags: elixir, ecto, subquery

This Ecto query works:

```
bid_players = from a in Auction,
                where: a.id == 1,
                join: bids in assoc(a, :bids),
                join: player in assoc(bids, :player),
                select: player.id
```

And this query works:

```
players = from player in Player,
            where: player.year_range == ^a.year_range,
            select: player.id
```

But I can't figure out how to get the players who are not bid players. When I try this:

```
not_bid_players = from player in Player,
                    where: player.year_range == ^a.year_range,
                    select: player.id,
                    except_all: ^bid_players
```

...I get:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) unsupported :except_all in keyword query expression
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.from/2
    iex:35: (file)
```

I guess there's something about `except_all` (see https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#except_all/2) that I don't understand.

Comment: I've never used this one before but is there a chance that you are simply using a version of Ecto that doesn't have `except_all`?

Comment: From my mix.exs file: `{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},`. And https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html shows version 3.2.1.

Comment: `{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"}` may still use Ecto which is < 3.0, in which apparently that keyword was introduced, so run `mix deps` and check what version is actually used.

Comment: `mix deps` shows `phoenix_ecto 3.6.0` and `ecto 2.2.12`. See my comments on Kalvin Hom's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`except_all` was added in Ecto 3.
phoenix_ecto needs to be at 4.0 to use Ecto 3+, looks like you need to upgrade.

Comment: Where is it documented that `except_all` was added in Ecto 3?

Comment: As I commented on the question, `mix deps` shows `phoenix_ecto 3.6.0` and `ecto 2.2.12`. I guess `phoenix_ecto` needs to be 4.0 so `ecto` itself is 3.x, right?

Comment: @DarylSpitzer you can find the Ecto changelogs in the github repository.

https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md